# C# MongoDB can't find MongoClient.cs

Tags: c#, mongodb

Whenever I use breakpoint on a method to insert a document, I get a "Can't find MongoClient.cs" issue. I still can connect to server and retrieve documents, which is 2.6.5 if it can help, and C# driver is version 1.10. I even downloaded the MongoClient.cs file from the github repository to use in the Visual Studio, but i get an error that says the source file is different from the module is built.

```
using MongoDB;
using MongoDB.Bson;
using MongoDB.Driver;
using MongoDB.Driver.Linq;
using MongoDB.Driver.Builders;


namespace WpfApplication1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {

    MongoClient mongoClient { get; set; }
    MongoServer server { get; set; }
    MongoDatabase database { get; set; }
    MongoCollection<facultyData> collection { get; set; }
    BindingList<facultyData> resultBinding { get; set; }
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
public void addData_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                MongoClient mongoClient= new MongoClient();
                var server = mongoClient.GetServer();
                var database = server.GetDatabase("facultyDataAndSchedule");
                var collection = database.GetCollection<facultyData>("faculty");
                var results = collection.FindAll();
                List<facultyData> resultList = results.ToList<facultyData>();
                BindingList<facultyData> resultBinding = new BindingList<facultyData>(resultList);
                try
                {
                    var entity = new facultyData
                    {
                        facultyID = facultyID_Textbox.Text.ToString(),
                        term = termComboBox.SelectedItem.ToString(),
                        age = int.Parse(age_TextBox.Text),
                        acadYear = "2014-2015",
                        firstName = firstName_TextBox.Text.ToString(),
                        lastName = lastName_TextBox.Text.ToString(),
                        middleName = middleName_TextBox.Text.ToString(),
                        dateOfBirth = dateOfBirth_TextBox.Text.ToString(),
                        program = "progra",
                        rank = "gegs",
                        services = "gegsg",
                        status = "geh",
                        yearsOfTeachingO = 1,
                        yearsOfTeachingS = 1
                    };
                    collection.Insert(entity);
                }
                catch (FormatException ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(ex);
                }
                resultBinding.ResetBindings();
                if (resultBinding.Count() > 0)
                {
                    Binding bind = new Binding(); //create a new binding to be used on the wpf 
                    facultyDataGrid.DataContext = resultBinding; //sets the data binding for the control
                    facultyDataGrid.SetBinding(DataGrid.ItemsSourceProperty, bind); //syncs the data
                }
            }
            catch (MongoConnectionException ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex);
            }   
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

It is ok that it cannot find the file. The Mongo client that you are using is the compiled assembly, not the code and debug files that Visual Studio wants to use for step through and break points. It is also normal that you are getting a notification that the code file is different from the module built. In the code file, you will probably find assembly conditions for debug and the like that will not be in the built module.

Long story short, what you experiencing is normal and you generally do not need to step through a distributed assembly.